# Code doesn't execute HttpResponse for second time when called twice

Tags: android, http, response, httpresponse

I'm doing and app who calls the same method two times and the second time I call the method it doesn't execute the line with HttResponse.

Here is the AsyncTask where everything starts:

```
private class FetchSubjectsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Subject>> {
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected List<Subject> doInBackground(String... params) {

        List<Subject> subjects = null;
        try {
            subjects = api.getMySubjects(params[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return subjects; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Subject> result) {

        printSubjects(result);

        if (pd != null) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get the subjects through the method getMySubjects which is:

```
public List<Subject> getMySubjects(String username) {
    List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
    java.lang.reflect.Type arrayListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Subject>>() {
    }.getType();
    String url = BASE_URL_VM + "users/" + username + "/subjects";
    HttpClient httpClient = WebServiceUtils.getHttpClient();
    try {
        System.out.println("inside try");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        System.out.println("response executed");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
        subjects = gson.fromJson(reader, arrayListType);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    System.out.println("Array lenght " +subjects.size());
    return subjects;
}
```

That's the first time HttpResponse executes and I get the "response executed" and "Array lenght 2" which are the number of subjects that user (username) has in the database.

The problem is when in onPostExecute I call the method printSubjects which is:

```
private void printSubjects(List<Subject> subjects){
    adapter = new SubjectAdapter(this,(ArrayList<Subject>)subjects, (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("username"));
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This calls the SubjectAdapter which prints the Subjects in a ListView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {  
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subject_detail, null);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.tvsubject = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tvsubject);

    boolean match = api.checkMySubjects(username, data.get(position).getId());

    Button addButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    if(match){
        addButton.setText("Delete");
    }else{
        addButton.setText("Add");
    }

    String content = data.get(position).getName();
    viewHolder.tvsubject.setText(content);
    }
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvsubject;
    TextView tvauthor;
}
```

There I call the method checkMySubjects which calls again getMySubjects to compare.

```
public boolean checkMySubjects(String username, String id) {
    List<Subject> mySubjects = getMySubjects(username);
    boolean match = false;
    for (Subject s1 : mySubjects) {
        if (s1.getId().equals(id)) {
            match = true;
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

But now the method getMySubjects doesn't arrive until "Response executed" and the Array lenght is 0. It only shows "Inside try".
Why? I'm calling the same method with the same URL but first time I get the 2 subjects in the array and the second time I get nothing because HttResponse doesn't execute.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's happening, but I'd like to point out what I think it's wrong. First, let's state the fact that`getMySubjects` performs a network operation, now, the first time you call it, it is called from within an `AsyncTask` on a thread other than the UI thread. This is perfectly fine

Then you call `printSubjects` in `onPostExecute` which populates a `ListView` with the results...

```
private void printSubjects(List<Subject> subjects){
    adapter = new SubjectAdapter(this,(ArrayList<Subject>)subjects, (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("username"));
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now, the problem is in your `getView` implementation of the adapter. More specifically here...

```
boolean match = api.checkMySubjects(username, data.get(position).getId());
```

this is terribly bad because you are making a network connection on the UI thread everytime you inflate a ListView item, so if you had ten items you will be making a network connection ten times (plus everytime you you scroll up and/or down the list).

Moreover, Android complains with a FATAL exception if you attempt to make a network connection on the UI thread. You're not even noticing because you are not doing anything with this exception...

```
try {
        System.out.println("inside try");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        System.out.println("response executed");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
        subjects = gson.fromJson(reader, arrayListType);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

the `catch` block is empty, if you print it to the LogCat you'll see the details

#### Suggestion

1. Don't make a network connection on the UI thread...you can't
2. On `getView` instead of making a network connection for every single iteration, eagerly load the data in memory before you set the ListView

Again, the offending line of code is...

```
boolean match = api.checkMySubjects(username, data.get(position).getId());
```

in `getView`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I see what you're saying but I don't know how to solve the problem. Should I find a way to do it on the background in AsyncTask?

Comment: @Alhar It's alright. Unfortunately I can't code a whole solution for you here. But, yes, an `AsyncTask`, a `Thread` or anything that doesn't run on the UI thread. Retrieve all the data you need before setting the Adapter on the `ListView` rather than getting data inside the `getView` method